# Unity3D dynamic mesh with hole

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, mesh, polygons

Dynamically creating a mesh with a hole in it from two lists of vertices
I am currently attempting to dynamically create a mesh (2D) with a hole in it. I have a list of Vector3 vertices for both the outline and the hole's outline.

My question:

How would I go about merging these two lists of vertices into a single mesh?
[image]

More detail: I have two meshes that overlap, and I'm trying to do a boolean difference between the two, to create a new mesh that will eventually replace the bigger one, to get rid of clipping. Example

Using the Clipper-Library (see http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) is of no use, because it returns the same two sets of vertices that I set as input.

I'm guessing I need to somehow fix the triangles for the mesh to create triangles between the outer and inner vertices? (The meshes can be any shape/size, so finding out which vertexes to combine into triangles is no easy task).

Can anybody tell me how I would create a single mesh out of the two vertex-loops?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a generic boolean algorithm this is a very hard problem, for example 3D Studio Max has two seperate boolean mesh creators, each failing at different sets of objects.

If you only need to subtract rectangular, aligned shapes, which do not touch, its simpler. For your specific case you can just join the list of vertexes, and fill new list of triangles - you'll need two tris per quad, so thats eight triangles stretched across eight verices.

It gets a bit harder if they start to touch, as you need to find intersection points and basically re-triangulate the outline.

Comment: I already know that they DON'T touch, as my algorithm is creating meshes for each cyle in a graph (meaning that if they touch, 3 meshes are created, and I can filter out the incorrect ones).
I just need to find out how to create a single mesh from the two sets of vertices (for the 'outer' polygon)